# asp.net c# change editbutton style programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I make a website,and I have a gridview like below:

```
欲查詢帳號:<asp:TextBox ID="txt_userid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
欲查詢日期:<asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn_isreplied" runat="server" Text="選擇尚未回覆" OnClick="btn_isreplied_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btn_search" runat="server" Text="查詢" OnClick="btn_search_Click" />
<br />
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
   OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
   OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
   OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
   AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="sno">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

[1] :https://ppt.cc/fzgM9x "gridview"

But I want to change my editbutton、updatebutton、cancelbutton from linkbutton style to button,how I can do?

Comment: You want to change it from like a hyperlink-field to a button while on the grid?

Comment: Yes,this is what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

You have to use TemplateFields and place some buttons in there. Then you have to give those buttons reserved `CommandName` like Edit, Update etc. Those correspond to the `OnRowUpdating` and `OnRowEditing` events.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
         <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```